# Access on Windows Server file share OK with hostname (or FQDN) but not with IP?

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2012

I can access a remote (via VPN) file share on a Windows 2012 DC but not with IP.

This works flawlessly: \\dc1\share1
This raises error: \\192.168.20.10\share1 (error: cannot access. check name etc.)

Didn't find any clue in server log files. Did not even find something on the internet. Ping/nslookup works like a charm. IPv6 deactivated. 4 NIC's in system (but 3 deactivated --- ???)

Hints and clues very welcomed :-)

Cheers,
hansli

Comment: If you explore to just `\\192.168.20.10` what happens? Is the share listed?

Comment: whats the output of `nbtstat -A  <ipaddress>`

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-2003/cannot-access-shared-folders-by-ip-address-but-i-can-by-name/11206.html) is a link to a thread with someone who had this same issue. He solved it by deleting all the network adapters from the Device Manager, restarting the server, and reinstalling the adapters.

This led one of the people in the linked thread to guess that nic binding to ipv6 vs ipv4 was the issue. In your case, IPv6 is disabled, so I'm not sure if this would apply.

Comment: I habitually disable IPv6 on windows for exactly this reason.